# how to preprocess data for classification in weka

Tags: algorithm, classification, weka

I am starting to use WEKA and I want to use the k-NN classifier on [this](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Parkinsons) dataset
I am able to import the dataset into weka. But when i want to start the classifier, there it does not show me any information about how much instances where correctly classified and how much not. I want to classify according to the status column. I guess i have to do some sort of preprocessing here because the status attribute is interpreted as a numerical value. ?! Can anybody explain what sorts of preprocessing i have to do for this kind of dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is probably to replace the numerical values in the status column with strings so that Weka recognises that they are categorical values.

Comment: What i now did is using the "numericalToNominal" filter on the attribute so that weka recognize the attribute to be nominal. Now the output of the classifier gives me more informations about correct and incorrect classified instances. Is this also a correct solution?

Comment: Yes. That's probably even easier.